# show/hide span while fetching json from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, getjson, imageicon

I have to show pageviews which i do using google analytics. Below is the html where i will show the page views

```
Pageviews: <span id="pageViews"></span>
           <span id="loadingGA">
                 <img height="12" alt="Loading..." src="../jsonData/images/waiting_icon.gif">
           </span>
```

So as you see, I have two spans one will display the page view count whiel other is for showing the loading icon till the page views are fetched.
The method which I am using is :

```
$("#loadingGA").hide()
    .ajaxStart(function() {
        $(this).show();
    }).ajaxStop(function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $("#pageViews").show();
    });
```

And below is how I am fetching the page views

```
function setPageviewsCount(url, displayId) {
var pageViews = "0";
$.getJSON(url, function(googleAnaltyicsData) {
    $.each(googleAnaltyicsData, function(i, gaData) {
        if(!jQuery.isEmptyObject(gaData)) {
            pageViews = gaData.PageViews;
        }
    });
    $(displayId).html(pageViews);
});}
```

The problem is, everything works fine but the loading icon doesn't disappear even after the page views get loaded. Tried every possible thing. Please guide.
Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a link to a site, or an example on jsFiddle?

Comment: Can you post your global ajax options? `If $.ajax() or $.ajaxSetup() is called with the global option set to false, the .ajaxStop() method will not fire.`

Comment: The [doc](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) say that `ajaxStart` or `ajaxStop` should only be attached to `document` -> `$(document).ajaxStart(function() {});`

Comment: What's the output of `console.log('ajaxStart)` in `ajaxStart()` and `console.log('ajaxStop)` in `ajaxStop()`?

Comment: Sorry brian, since its an internal project, It will take very long to provide a demo or something. Still would try for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [`.ajaxStop()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) and [`.ajaxStart()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) documentation

*quote*

> **As of jQuery 1.8, however, the `.ajaxStop()` method should only be
>   attached to `document`.**

and

> **As of jQuery 1.8, however, the `.ajaxStart()` method should only be
>   attached to `document`.**

```
$("#loadingGA").hide();

$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    $('#loadingGA').show();
}).ajaxStop(function () {
    $('#loadingGA').hide();
    $("#pageViews").show();
});
```

Comment: This worked. Only that first line $("#loadingGA").hide(); isn't required as that was making the icon hide completely.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [jQuery spec](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/), you should attach `.ajaxStart` and `.ajaxStop` only to `document` as of jQuery 1.8.0.

Try this:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    $("#loadingGA").show();
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    $("#loadingGA").hide();
});
```

Comment: Use `console.log()` to see if the events actually fire. Maybe the response (error or OK) comes back so quick, you don't actually see the icon appear before it disappears again?

Comment: yeah.. it was actually quick. But yes now its fixed. Previous answer was very much helpful